# The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is Required Code For my application . I am getting error stated above in my Account Controller file . I am using built in Account Register & Login code in MVC 4 . Unable to register the User . I have seen link below on stackoverflow tosolve my error but unable to get it solved

[Link I Followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893710/the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context)

**My Connection Strings in My Web.Config Code**

```
  <connectionStrings>
 <add name="PromoteMyNameEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PromoteDB.csdl|res://*/PromoteDB.ssdl|res://*/PromoteDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Dell-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PromoteMyName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=Dell-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PromoteMyName;integrated security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

 <connectionStrings>
```

**IdentityModel.cs File**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace PromoteMyName.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

**My DbContent File**

```
public partial class PromoteMyNameEntities1 : DbContext
    {
        public PromoteMyNameEntities1()
            : base("name=PromoteMyNameEntities1")
        {
        }
```

**AccountController.CS ( Getting Error in This File )**

```
 // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

  //Getting Error at Line Below
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("BusinessCategory", "ClientBusinesses");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: You have two contexts:  PromoteMyNameEntities1 and ApplicationDbContext.  The PromoteMyNameEntities1 don't extends IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, because of this you have this error.

Comment: how can i extend that

Comment: Something like this:  public ApplicationDbContext()  : base("PromoteMyNameEntities1", throwIfV1Schema: false)

Comment: currently they are not linked i can link them by userid

Comment: do i need to first link them then i need to use code above in idenitymodel.cs

Comment: no, no, I deleted this question, I'm sorry.  You are telling EF that you have two databases, one for users, other for you model.  You need to point to the same fisical database.

Comment: I am having only one database . EIther I use one connection string or two same error exist

Comment: you can see in both connection string db name and connection is same

Comment: In the migrations folder, do you have two Configuration.cs classes, one for user's context and other for you model context?  I have two.  If you want to have two separated contexts.

Comment: i am using dbfirst approach so i am not having migrations folder

Comment: Oh, I can't help then, I'm sorry.  :-(

Comment: don't you deal with db first

Comment: No, I use Code First, with migrations.  I have two configuration classes.  And separate migrations for users or model.

Comment: ok no worries i need to find this way

Comment: This could help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940014/asp-net-identity-with-ef-database-first-mvc5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point 1 :** I have seen in your web.config you are having two connections string but both are using same connection and same db so you don't require second one . Remove the below line from your web.config

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=Dell-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PromoteMyName;integrated security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Point 2 :** I think you have done some trouble with inbuilt Membership Db Sure Short Solution for you problem is go to your db remove the Aspnet / Inbuilt tables ( i mean to drop the tables in db that are created by code first membership )

After removing those tables . Now Clean the Solution and Then ReBuild the solution , Then Run the Solution It will automatically create the new memebership tables in the database .

Comment: Thanks, I will be trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using IdentityUser instead of ApplicationUser,will Solve the problem