# Getting the error "Entity Type Users is not part of the model for the current context" in a DB first MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My DB context was created via the DB first approach and after it was created, I noticed one of the tables I needed was not listed in my DB context so I created a model class for it then added it into the list of DBSet properties. I have a linq statement in my controller action that is referencing the new model so I can pass a query to the view. However upon running, its coming back with

> The entity type **Users** is not part of the model for the current context.

**DBContext:**

```
   public partial class DevEntities : DbContext
{
    public DevEntities(): base("name=DevEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TeamStats> TeamStats { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<QuarterlyReport> QuarterlyReport { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

With that said, is there is an easy fix for this? and is there a reason the model for my Users table would not have been created when it created the other models and contexts?

Comment: What happens if you replace `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();` with `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you comment out `public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }` and try running the program and registering?

Comment: Anyway, I'm still a newbie and trying to learn this stuff.  This thread might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893710/the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context

Comment: Also this might be helpful, although it pertains mainly to code first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx