# Entity Framework ConnectionString Not Working

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

From as far as I can tell all of the questions that relate to this have not solved my issue. 
I have an sql database hosted by Azure. Super simple, I want to connect it to my ASP.Net MVC app using Entity Framework.

Data Model has been added and edmx file is present,
Connection string

```
  <connectionStrings><add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="...serverinfo"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

I go to my IdentityModels.cs and change the following

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyDatabase", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

When i go to register a user in hopes that the users information will be added to my Azure database i get the following; "**The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.**"

I am kind of at my end on this. If someone can point me to documentation to build and applicaiton based upon a previously created database that I can follow  or know what I am missing please let me know.  Thank you

Comment: ref this lnk if something for you..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893710/the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to access the entity? Also Set the initializer of Application Context to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Edit your Connection String and Modify your code as Follow - 

<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyDatabasedbEntitiesapplication"   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="database and username password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
<add name="MyDatabasedbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=yourdatasource,1433;initial catalog=yourdbname;user id=username;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>


Modify the code:

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyDatabase", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

Modify AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; in Configuration class under Migrations folder.
```

Comment: Why would it want the removal of Entities?  The solutions works but I am still not sure why we need to remove "Entities" from the applicationDbContext.  Thank you for the help.