# Entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context (duplicate)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

After reading more than 20 pages about this subject im constraint to ask help

Im using C# MVC .ASP NET CORE
I want to host the user of the application on the sql database => not on the local database

I added the AspNetUsers tables in my database (like this)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixqU7.png)
And changed in Models/IdentityModels.cs

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("dbApp", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

with the good string connection name from Web.config

Somemone can say me why i get this error :

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Thanks all

Comment: Because title of topic need to be unique (but why are you asking me this ????)

Comment: Because if the title already exists, then the question has already been asked and you shouldn't be asking it again :)

Comment: Yes im according to you, but if the topic dont answer my problem, how i do ? This question was posted lot of time, you can check ^^

Comment: And every time it is posted, people write the same answers.

Comment: Not really because this error message is used for multiple cases

Comment: No it isn't, this error is very specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893710/the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context)